# @image-added event is not working in vue-editor@2.10.2

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

hello i have a problom with image-added event in vue-editor this is my code

```
    <div class="editor">
            <vue-editor :editorOptions="editorSettings" v-model="blogHTML" useCustomImageHandler @image-added="imageHandler"> </vue-editor>
    </div>
```

and this is my fuction

```
methods: {
    imageHandler(file, Editor, cursorLocation, resetUploader) {
        console.log('hello')
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref()
        const docRef = storageRef.child(`documents/blogPostPhotos/${file.name}`)
        docRef.put(file).on("state_changed", 
            snapshot => {
                console.log(snapshot)
            }, err => {
                console.log(err)
            },
            async () => {
                const downloadURL = await docRef.getDownloadURL();
                Editor.insertEmbed(cursorLocation, "image", downloadURL);
                resetUploader();
            }
        )
    },
},
```

the problem is the function is not running and there is no error messages

Answer (score 2):

try changing **@image-added** for **@imageAdded** as it says in the documentation, right here:

https://www.vue2editor.com/examples/#custom-image-handler